# I have 3 indices in Pandas DataFrame, can I add a column that matches to the middle index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

[First DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMPu9.png)

and another that looks like this:

[Second DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlOsw.png)

Which I would like to combine, and get something that looks like this:

[Third DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC6mg.png)

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried merging and joining but every time I do it it drops the transaction # column, if possible I would like to have it join on the name column but still keep the transaction column is basically what I'm trying to do. So that whichever row has a name, has a net volume. TIA

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Strateg', 'Name'])`?

Comment: @Ricardo when I do that it gets rid of the transaction number column for some reason

Comment: Try `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Strategy', 'Name'], how='left')`